# Saving 16 bit (each channel) game render in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to save the game render/texture from Unity. But, it seems that Unity doesn't support exporting game render in 16 bit format for each channel. Any pointers on this issue?

Comment: Sorry are you grabbing a texture2d from the camera? Or the screen, or what?

Comment: @awiebe : We are grabbing the rendered game scene from a camera.

Comment: Texture2D.GetPixels() will allow you to retrieve the data from the texture, then you can map the values into your desired colorspace.